# Create Website with Facebook API to collect invited User ID's

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am looking to integrate Facebook into my website. The website is basically an online meeting and the user has to know the host's username to log in. I was wondering if there is a way withing the Facebook API to invite specific users and link them to this meeting object, I was thinking by pulling the invited users User ID and inputting it into a database, so that when the guest goes to the party they just have to log into Facebook and it will bring them to the correct party (by MySQL search matching their user ID with a meeting). I hope I explained this correctly, but is there a way to do this with the API, or even a better way to complete this?

Comment: I don’t get what you want completely. But before a usr has connected to your ap, you don’t get any info about them, not even the FB user id.

Comment: I understand that, I mean like is there an ability to have a user (logged into facebook) select friends and then be able to return their ID's so I can log them in a database for later use.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/custom-muti-friend-selector/